# Flask: how to receive all characters passed to the variable section?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I have a simple web service:

```
from flask import Flask, escape

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/test/<path:variable>')
    def print_variable(variable):
        return 'Variable: %s' % escape(variable)
```

When I run in the browser:

```
http://localhost:5000/test/https://www.whydoyoucut.com/stat.phtml?u=value1&g=value2
```

I receive:

```
Variable: https://www.whydoyoucut.com/stat.phtml
```

My goal is to receive:

```
Variable: https://www.whydoyoucut.com/stat.phtml?u=value1&g=value2
```

What changes should I introduce to the code to reach that?

Answer (score 1):

From what I could understand, you are able to get the string but you are missing the arguments. You can use request.args to get those. Following code snippet should work for you:

```
from flask import Flask, escape, request

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/test/<path:variable>')
def print_variable(variable):
    print(variable)
    print(request.args.get('u'))
    print(request.args.get('g'))
    return 'Variable: %s' % escape(variable)
```

Comment: What if arguments' names (`u`, `g`) are unknown?

Comment: @Czarek request.args.items() would return a list of tuples of keys and corresponding values.
If you just want the keys, then request.args.keys() would give you a list of the keys..

Answer (score 1):

As Upendra said, you can use request.args the get the query string from your url.

To return the url passed to your api, you can do something like:

```
from flask import Flask, escape, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/test/<path:variable>')
def print_variable(variable):
    return_value = escape(variable)

    if request.args:
        return_value += '?'
        return_value += '&'.join([f'{k}={v}' for k, v in request.args.items()])

    return 'Variable: %s' % return_value
```

Here we are just appending ? and the args if it was given. 
You'll just need to format the [ImmutableMultiDict](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/0.16.x/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.ImmutableMultiDict) received by the [flask.Request](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.request).

The result is:

```
request: http://127.0.0.1:10000/test/https://www.whydoyoucut.com/stat.phtml?u=value1&g=value2
response: Variable: https://www.whydoyoucut.com/stat.phtml?u=value1&g=value2

request: http://127.0.0.1:10000/test/https://www.whydoyoucut.com/stat.phtml
response: Variable: https://www.whydoyoucut.com/stat.phtml
```